Change html table color based on the value of a cell
I am fetching data from an API and displaying it in a html table.
Now I want to change the color of the rows based on the value of a column.
For example if status is Accepted then green row and if status is not accepted then red color row.


const url = "https://dummyjson.com/c/38f5-f39a-411e-aeb0";

fetch(url).then(
  res => {
    res.json().then(
      data => {
        //console.log(data.data);
        if (data.data.length > 0) {
          var temp = "";
          data.data.forEach((itemData) => {
            temp += "<tr>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.Name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.Address + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.Status + "</td></tr>";
          });
          document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp
        }
      }
    )
  }
)
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,th {
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>




To dynamically change the row color in a table based on the value of a particular column, you can follow the approach below. I have used the JSONPlaceholder REST API for testing purposes, but the idea remains the same for any API.


     fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          } else {
            throw new Error("API request failed");
          }
        })
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.length > 0) {
            let temp = "";
            data.forEach((itemData) => {
              const rowClass = itemData.completed
                ? "completed-row"
                : "not-completed-row";

              temp += `<tr class="${rowClass}">`;
              temp += `<td>${itemData.id}</td>`;
              temp += `<td>${itemData.title}</td>`;
              temp += `<td>${itemData.completed}</td></tr>`;
            });

            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp;
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log("Error fetching data:", error));
      .completed-row {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
      }

      .not-completed-row {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
      }
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Completed</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>




It is working for normal tables. But with bootstrap table its not working.

@ShubhamSinghChauhan i have used custom css to change the color of the rows (.completed-row and .not-completed-row) these classes are not part of bootstrap. if you want to use bootstrap's classes use: const rowClass = itemData.completed ? "table-success" : "table-danger";

In order to change the row color as per the status value, you can add conditional logic while generating the rows. Also you can apply the appropriate CSS class or inline styles to the <tr> element depending on the status.
fetch("some url").then(
  res => {
    res.json().then(
      data => {
        if (data.data.length > 0) {
          var temp = "";
          data.data.forEach((itemData) => {
            let rowColor = itemData.Status === "Accepted" ? "green" : "red";
            temp += `<tr style="background-color: ${rowColor};">`;
            temp += `<td>${itemData.Name}</td>`;
            temp += `<td>${itemData.Address}</td>`;
            temp += `<td>${itemData.Status}</td></tr>`;
          });
          document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
        }
      }
    );
  }
);

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


Here is a simpler method using template literals since you use innerHTML anyway.


const url = "https://dummyjson.com/c/38f5-f39a-411e-aeb0";
const tBody = document.getElementById('data');
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(({data}) => tBody.innerHTML = data
    .map(itemData => `<tr class="${itemData.Status==='Accepted' ? 'green' : 'red'}">
    <td>${itemData.Name}</td>
    <td>${itemData.Address}</td>
    <td>${itemData.Status}</td>
    </tr>`).join('')
  )
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




When creating a TR Element, set its className to the user.Status value:


const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

const getUsers = async () => {
  let users = [];
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/c/38f5-f39a-411e-aeb0");
    const data = await res.json();
    users = data.data;
  } catch (err) { console.error(err); }
  return users;
};

const drawUsersData = async () => {
  const elData = el("#data");
  const users = await getUsers();
  const rows = users.map((user) => {
    return elNew("tr", {
      className: user.Status,
      innerHTML: `
         <td>${user.Name}</td>
         <td>${user.Address}</td>
         <td>${user.Status}</td>
       `
    });
  });
  
  elData.innerHTML = "";
  elData.append(...rows);
};

drawUsersData();
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

tr.Accepted {
  color: green;
}
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data"></tbody>
</table>



